# Game keeps crashing without even getting to the splash screen on Oreo

Tags: java, android, security, crash, google-people-api

I am an indie game developer and I had my first game on the Play Store for two years running fine. But suddenly when phones started to upgrade to Android Oreo, every time the game is launched it crashes without even showing the splash screen. I thought this was a problem with my phone, but it seems to happen in any device that has Android Oreo in it.

I've been using GameMaker Studio 1.4 to develop my game, and recently even upgraded and built it in GameMaker Studio 2 to test if the issue would be gone, but nothing changed.

Ok, so I come to the conclusion the issue might be related to the Google Play Services extension. But if I remove it the game still crashes!
Also, the Google Play Developer Console alerts me that I've implemented "Achievements" incorrectly in my game, but that doesn't even make any sense, because achievements have always worked fine in all versions of the game.

It's been months since I've got this issue and I haven't found any help so far. It can't be code-related because the game crashes as soon as I touch it's icon... it doesn't even get me to the splash screen, which comes before any code, right?

I ran the game in Debug Mode and the report gets me lots of errors like this:

```
--------- beginning of crash
10-24 20:20:11.160  8521  8538 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 6135
10-24 20:20:11.160  8521  8538 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.playhouse.ghosthitch, PID: 8521
10-24 20:20:11.160  8521  8538 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown type
10-24 20:20:11.160  8521  8538 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.opengl.GLUtils.getType(GLUtils.java:71)
10-24 20:20:11.160  8521  8538 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.opengl.GLUtils.texSubImage2D(GLUtils.java:189)
10-24 20:20:11.160  8521  8538 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.playhouse.ghosthitch.DemoRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(DemoRenderer.java:332)
10-24 20:20:11.160  8521  8538 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1539)
10-24 20:20:11.160  8521  8538 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1270)
```

[EDIT] This is the code for the **DemoRenderer.java** file:

```
package ${YYAndroidPackageName};

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL11;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.System;
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.util.Locale;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;
import android.opengl.GLES11Ext;
import android.opengl.GLDebugHelper;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.app.Application;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.ConfigurationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.Manifest;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
//import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import com.yoyogames.runner.RunnerJNILib;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.MissingResourceException;

/*
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import android.util.Base64;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
*/

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class DemoRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
{
    public enum eState 
    {
        Startup,
        DownloadGameDroidInit,
        DownloadGameDroidWait,
        Splash,
        Splash2,
        APKExpansionDownload,
        InitRunner,
        WaitForDoStartup,
        WaitOnTimer,
        DoStartup,
        Process,
    };
    public static eState m_state;
    public int m_renderCount;
    private Context m_context;
    private int m_width;
    private int m_height;
    public static String m_apkFilePath;
    private String m_packageName;

    public static String m_saveFilesDir;

    private int m_texWidth;
    private int m_texHeight;
    private int m_texRawWidth;
    private int m_texRawHeight;
    public static final String kGameAssetsDROID = "GameAssetsDROID.zip";

    private String m_splashFilePath = "assets/splash.png";

    public static final int RUNNER_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST = 0x55;

    public boolean m_RequestedPermissions = false;


    public static int m_defaultFrameBuffer = -1;
    public static boolean ms_displayedLoadLibraryFailed = false;

    public int m_pausecountdown =-1;
    public boolean m_pauseRunner = false;
    private Map<String, Locale> localeMap;

    private long splashEndTime = 0;

    public float m_refreshRate = 60.0f;
    public static volatile Object waiterObject = null;
    public static volatile int elapsedVsyncs = -1;  

    private void initCountryCodeMapping() {
        String[] countries = Locale.getISOCountries();
        localeMap = new HashMap<String, Locale>(countries.length);
        for (String country : countries) {
            Locale locale = new Locale("", country);
            localeMap.put(locale.getISO3Country().toUpperCase(Locale.US), locale);
        }
    }   

    private String iso3CountryCodeToIso2CountryCode(String iso3CountryCode) {
        if (localeMap != null) {
            Locale locale = localeMap.get(iso3CountryCode);
            if (locale != null) {
                return locale.getCountry();
            } // end if
            else {
                return iso3CountryCode;
            } // end else
        } // end if
        else {
            return iso3CountryCode;
        }
    }

    public DemoRenderer( Context _context )
    {
        waiterObject = new Object();
        m_context = _context;
        m_state = eState.Startup;
        m_renderCount = 0;
        m_packageName = m_context.getPackageName();     
    }   

    public InputStream getResourceAsReader( String path)
    {
        System.out.println(path);
        try{
            android.content.res.AssetManager assetManager = m_context.getResources().getAssets();
            return assetManager.open(path);
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception while getting Resource");         
            return null;
        }
    }   

    private int getNextPow2(int _val)
    {       
        // Handle case where number is already a power-of-two
        _val--;

        // Smear bits downwards
        _val |= _val >> 1;
        _val |= _val >> 2;
        _val |= _val >> 4;
        _val |= _val >> 8;
        _val |= _val >> 16;

        // Value should be one less than a power-of-two so add 1
        _val++;

        // Finally, handle case where _val is 0
        if (_val == 0)
            _val++;     

        return _val;
    }

    public int getScreenOrientation()
    {
        return m_context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) 
    {       
        //GLDebugHelper.wrap(gl, GLDebugHelper.CONFIG_CHECK_GL_ERROR, null);


        if ((m_state != eState.Startup) && (m_state != eState.DownloadGameDroidWait)) {
            Log.i("yoyo", "onSurfaceCreated() aborted on re-create, state is currently "+m_state);
            return;
        }

        // Try and retrieve the current framebuffer if we haven't already got it
        if (m_defaultFrameBuffer == -1)
        {
            if (gl instanceof GL11) {
                IntBuffer intBuffer = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
                gl.glGetIntegerv(GLES11Ext.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING_OES, intBuffer);

                m_defaultFrameBuffer = intBuffer.get(0);
                Log.i("yoyo", "Renderer instance is gl1.1, framebuffer object is: " + m_defaultFrameBuffer);
            }
        }

        if (RunnerActivity.YoYoRunner) 
        {
            List<String> permissionstoreq = new ArrayList<String>();


            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >  android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            {
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    permissionstoreq.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }

                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    permissionstoreq.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
            }


            if(permissionstoreq.size()>0)
            {
                String []perms = new String[permissionstoreq.size()];
                permissionstoreq.toArray(perms);
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity,perms,RUNNER_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
                m_saveFilesDir = "";
                m_RequestedPermissions=true;
            }   
            else
            {

                m_saveFilesDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/GMstudio";
                File studioDir = new File( m_saveFilesDir );
                studioDir.mkdir();
                m_saveFilesDir = m_saveFilesDir + '/';
            }
        }
        else
        {       
            m_saveFilesDir = m_context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/";
        } // end else

        m_apkFilePath = null;
        ApplicationInfo appInfo = null;
        PackageManager packMgmr = m_context.getPackageManager();
        try {
            appInfo = packMgmr.getApplicationInfo("${YYAndroidPackageName}", 0);
        } 
        catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to locate assets, aborting...");
        } // end catch
        m_apkFilePath = appInfo.sourceDir;

        Log.i("yoyo", "APK File Path :: " + m_apkFilePath );

        // load splash screen in and bind it 
        int[] textures = new int[1];
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);


        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,  textures[0]);

        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

        //gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        //gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        //gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_REPLACE);

        ActivityManager activityMgmr = (ActivityManager)m_context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ConfigurationInfo info = activityMgmr.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
        if (info.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000) {
            Log.i("yoyo", "OpenGL ES-2.0 is supported: " + info.reqGlEsVersion);
        }
        else {
            Log.i("yoyo", "OpenGL ES-CM 1.1 is supported: " + info.reqGlEsVersion);
        }

        // load the actual texture in
        InputStream is;
        if (getScreenOrientation() == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ) {
            is = getResourceAsReader( "splash.png" );
        } else {
            m_splashFilePath = "assets/portrait_splash.png";
            is = getResourceAsReader( "portrait_splash.png" );
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opt.inDither=false;
            opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( is, null, opt );
            m_texWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
            m_texHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        } 
        finally 
        {
            try {
                is.close();
            } 
            catch ( IOException _e ) {
                // do nothing
            } // end catch

        }

        m_texRawWidth = getNextPow2(m_texWidth);
        m_texRawHeight = getNextPow2(m_texHeight);
        //Log.i("yoyo", "Splashscreen w" + m_texWidth + " h" + m_texHeight);
        //Log.i("yoyo", "Rawtex w" + m_texRawWidth + " h" + m_texRawHeight);
        Bitmap pow2Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(m_texRawWidth, m_texRawHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  ##### GLUtils.texImage2D( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, pow2Bitmap, 0);
        GLUtils.texSubImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, bitmap);
        bitmap.recycle();

        /*if (m_context == null)
        {
            Log.i("yoyo", "Context is null!!!!!");
        }

        if (m_context.getCacheDir() == null)
        {
            Log.i("yoyo", "Context.getCacheDir() is null!!!!!");
        }

        if (m_context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() == null)
        {
            Log.i("yoyo", "Context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() is null!!!!!");
        }*/

        initCountryCodeMapping();
        if (RunnerJNILib.ms_loadLibraryFailed) {
            return;
        } // end if
        RunnerJNILib.SetKeyValue( 0, RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity.isTablet() ? 1 : 0, "" );
        RunnerJNILib.SetKeyValue( 1, 0, m_context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
        RunnerJNILib.SetKeyValue( 2, 0, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage() );
        RunnerJNILib.SetKeyValue( 3, m_context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi, "" );
        RunnerJNILib.SetKeyValue( 4, m_context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi, "" );
        RunnerJNILib.SetKeyValue( 5, android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE );
        try {
            RunnerJNILib.SetKeyValue( 8, 0, iso3CountryCodeToIso2CountryCode(Locale.getDefault().getISO3Country()) );
        }
        catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            RunnerJNILib.SetKeyValue( 8, 0, "zz" );
        }       
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) 
    {    
        m_width = w;
        m_height = h;
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
        Log.i("yoyo", "onSurfaceChanged :: width="+m_width+" height="+m_height);
    }           

    public static void WaitForVsync()
    {
        long starttime = System.nanoTime();
        int currVsync = elapsedVsyncs;
        while((elapsedVsyncs != -1) && (currVsync == elapsedVsyncs))
        {
            long currtime = System.nanoTime();

            if ((currtime - starttime) > (100 * 1000 * 1000)) // tenth of a second
            {
                Log.i("yoyo", "vsync timeout...");
                break;
            }
        }

        /*synchronized(waiterObject)
        {
            while(currVsync == elapsedVsyncs)
            {
                try
                {
                    waiterObject.wait();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    if (currVsync == elapsedVsyncs)
                    {
                        Log.i("yoyo", "Thread interrupted prematurely");
                    }
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }*/
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

        if (RunnerJNILib.ms_loadLibraryFailed) {
            if (!ms_displayedLoadLibraryFailed) {
                ms_displayedLoadLibraryFailed = true;
                RunnerActivity.ViewHandler.post( new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RunnerJNILib.ms_context);
                            builder.setMessage("Unable to find library for this devices architecture, which is " + System.getProperty("os.arch") + ", ensure you have included the correct architecture in your APK")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton( "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int id ) {
                                        RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity.finish();
                                    }
                                });
                            AlertDialog alert  = builder.create();
                            alert.show();
                     }
                });
            } // end if
            return;
        } // end if

        if(m_pausecountdown>0)
        {
            m_pausecountdown--;
            if(m_pausecountdown<=0)
            {
                m_pauseRunner = true;
                //Log.i("yoyo","Setting m_pauseRunner due to alarm countdown ("+m_pausecountdown+")");
            }
        }

        // if we are paused then do go to sleep and don't do anything
        if (m_pauseRunner) {
            try {   
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.i("yoyo", "Paused runner has thrown an exception!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } // end catch
            return;
        }

        switch( m_state ) {
            case Startup:
                m_state = eState.Splash;
                Log.i("yoyo", "State->Splash");
                gl.glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
                gl.glClear( GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
                break;
            case Splash:
                if (RunnerActivity.mYYPrefs==null)          
                {
                    splashEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000);
                }
                else
                {
                    splashEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + (RunnerActivity.mYYPrefs.getInt("SplashscreenTime")*1000);
                }
                Log.i("yoyo", "State->Splash    time: "+System.currentTimeMillis());
                Log.i("yoyo", "State->Splash endTime: "+splashEndTime);
                if (RunnerActivity.YoYoRunner) {
                    m_state = eState.Splash2;
                    Log.i("yoyo", "State->Splash2");
                } // end if
                else if(RunnerActivity.UseAPKExpansionFile ) {
                    m_state = eState.APKExpansionDownload;
                    Log.i("yoyo", "State->APKExpansionDownload");
                }else {
                    Log.i("yoyo", "State->InitRunner");
                    m_state = eState.InitRunner;
                } // end else
                RunnerJNILib.RenderSplash( m_apkFilePath, m_splashFilePath, m_width, m_height, m_texRawWidth, m_texRawHeight, m_texWidth, m_texHeight );
                break;
            case Splash2:

                if(!m_RequestedPermissions)
                {
                    m_state = eState.DownloadGameDroidInit;
                    RunnerJNILib.RenderSplash( m_apkFilePath, m_splashFilePath, m_width, m_height, m_texRawWidth, m_texRawHeight, m_texWidth, m_texHeight );
                }

                break;
            case DownloadGameDroidInit:         
                RunnerJNILib.RenderSplash( m_apkFilePath, m_splashFilePath, m_width, m_height, m_texRawWidth, m_texRawHeight, m_texWidth, m_texHeight );
                m_apkFilePath = m_saveFilesDir + kGameAssetsDROID;
                File fAssets = new File( m_apkFilePath );
                Log.i("yoyo", "!!! Asset file - " + m_apkFilePath + " " + fAssets.exists() + " l=" + fAssets.lastModified() );
                File fLock = new File( m_saveFilesDir + "GameDownload.lock" );
                Log.i("yoyo", "!!! Lock file - " + fLock.getAbsolutePath() + " " + fLock.exists() + " l=" + fLock.lastModified() );

                if(RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity.HasRestarted)
                {
                    m_state = eState.InitRunner;
                }
                else if (!fLock.exists() || (fLock.exists() && (fLock.lastModified() < fAssets.lastModified()))) 
                {
                    m_saveFilesDir = m_context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/";
                    m_apkFilePath = m_saveFilesDir + kGameAssetsDROID;

                    Log.i("yoyo", "APK File Path DGDI:: " + m_apkFilePath );

                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( m_context );
                    String ipAddress = prefs.getString( "hostIpAddress", "none" );
                    String portNumber = prefs.getString( "hostPortNumber", "none" );


                    Log.i("yoyo","Found ipAddress "+ ipAddress + " in prefs");
                    Log.i("yoyo","Found portNumber "+ portNumber + " in prefs");

                    if(ipAddress.equals("none") || portNumber.equals("none"))
                    {
                        //Parse the .ini file that we have to grab the port & ip address 
                        Log.i("yoyo","Checking for ipaddress in inifile");
                        // Just use manifest file if this is a package
                        Bundle bundle = null;
                        try {
                            ApplicationInfo ai = m_context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity.getComponentName().getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                            bundle = ai.metaData;   

                        } catch( Exception _e ) {
                            Log.d( "yoyo", "Exception while setting up Ini" +_e.toString() );
                        } // end catch

                        if(bundle!=null)
                        {   
                            IniBundle lPrefs = new IniBundle( bundle, null );   

                            ipAddress = lPrefs.getString("YYHostIP");

                            if(ipAddress==null)
                                ipAddress="none";


                            int iportNumber = lPrefs.getInt("YYHostPort");
                            if(iportNumber!=0)
                                portNumber = Integer.toString(iportNumber);
                            else
                                portNumber = "none";
                            Log.i("yoyo","Found ipAddress "+ ipAddress + " in our manifest");
                            Log.i("yoyo","Found portNumber "+ portNumber + " in our manifest");
                        }
                        else
                            Log.d("yoyo","Bundle not found");

                    } 


                    final String url = "http://" + ipAddress + ":" + portNumber + "/" + kGameAssetsDROID;
                    RunnerActivity.DownloadTaskStatus = DownloadStatus.NotConnected;
                    m_state = eState.DownloadGameDroidWait;
                    RunnerActivity.ViewHandler.post( new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() {


                            boolean needstart = false;
                            if(RunnerActivity.DownloadTask == null)
                            {
                                RunnerActivity.DownloadTask = new RunnerDownloadTask();
                                needstart = true;
                            }
                            Log.i("yoyo","Attempting to download " + url + " to " +m_apkFilePath);
                            RunnerActivity.DownloadTask.TargetURL = url;
                            RunnerActivity.DownloadTask.DestPath = m_apkFilePath;

                            if((RunnerActivity.DownloadTask.getStatus()!= AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) && (RunnerActivity.DownloadTask.getStatus()!= AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED))
                            {
                                needstart = true;
                            }

                            if(needstart)
                            {
                                RunnerActivity.DownloadTask.execute( url, m_apkFilePath  );
                                Log.i("yoyo","Done execute downloadtask");
                            }


                        }
                     });
                } // end if
                else {
                    Log.i("yoyo", "GameDownload.lock exists, about to delete...");
                    fLock.delete();

                    Log.i("yoyo","After delete flock.exists() returns "+fLock.exists());
                    m_state = eState.InitRunner;
                } // end else
                break;
            case DownloadGameDroidWait:         
                RunnerJNILib.RenderSplash( m_apkFilePath, m_splashFilePath, m_width, m_height, m_texRawWidth, m_texRawHeight, m_texWidth, m_texHeight );


                switch( RunnerActivity.DownloadTaskStatus ) {
                case Error:
                case SettingsChanged:
                    m_state = eState.DownloadGameDroidInit;
                    Log.i("yoyo","In state DownloadGameDroidWait going to DownloadGameDroidInit");
                    break;
                case Complete:
                    m_state = eState.InitRunner;
                    Log.i("yoyo","In state DownloadGameDroidWait going to InitRunner");

                    break;
                } // end switch
                break;

            case APKExpansionDownload:
                //Log.i("yoyo", "APKExpansionDownload...");
                //where is apkFilePath pointing to here...? splash should be assets regardless...i think...
                RunnerJNILib.RenderSplash( m_apkFilePath, m_splashFilePath, m_width, m_height, m_texRawWidth, m_texRawHeight, m_texWidth, m_texHeight );
                if( RunnerActivity.APKExpansionFileReady ) 
                {
                    //set the new apk path
                    //m_apkFilePath = RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity.GetExpansionAPKFilename();

                    Object apkFilePath = RunnerJNILib.CallExtensionFunction("PlayAPKExpansionExtension","GetExpansionAPKFilename",0,null);
                    m_apkFilePath = (String)apkFilePath;

                    Log.i("yoyo", "Download complete- path is:" + m_apkFilePath );
                    m_state = eState.InitRunner;
                }
                break;

            case InitRunner:
                RunnerJNILib.RenderSplash( m_apkFilePath, m_splashFilePath, m_width, m_height, m_texRawWidth, m_texRawHeight, m_texWidth, m_texHeight );
                m_state = eState.WaitForDoStartup;
                RunnerActivity.ViewHandler.post( new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity.doSetup( m_apkFilePath );
                    }
                });
                break;

            case WaitForDoStartup:
                RunnerJNILib.RenderSplash( m_apkFilePath, m_splashFilePath, m_width, m_height, m_texRawWidth, m_texRawHeight, m_texWidth, m_texHeight );
                break;

            case WaitOnTimer:
                RunnerJNILib.RenderSplash( m_apkFilePath, m_splashFilePath, m_width, m_height, m_texRawWidth, m_texRawHeight, m_texWidth, m_texHeight );
                long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if ( time >= splashEndTime )
                    m_state = eState.DoStartup;
                break;

            case DoStartup:
                // free the textures
                int[] textures = new int[1];
                gl.glDeleteTextures(1, textures, 0);
                if (RunnerActivity.mYYPrefs==null)          
                        RunnerJNILib.Startup(m_apkFilePath, m_saveFilesDir, m_packageName, 0);
                else
                {
                        Log.i("yoyo","Sleepmargin: " + (RunnerActivity.mYYPrefs.getInt("SleepMargin")));
                        RunnerJNILib.Startup(m_apkFilePath, m_saveFilesDir, m_packageName, (RunnerActivity.mYYPrefs.getInt("SleepMargin")));
                }
                m_state = eState.Process;
                break;

            case Process:
                //gl.glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
                //gl.glClear( GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|GL10.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT );
                if(!RunnerJNILib.ms_exitcalled)
                {
                    int keypadStatus = 0;
                    if (RunnerActivity.XPeriaPlay && (m_context.getResources().getConfiguration().navigation == 2) &&  
                        (m_context.getResources().getConfiguration().navigationHidden == 1)) {
                        keypadStatus = 1;
                    } // end if
                    do{
                        //Log.i("yoyo","keypad status = " +  m_context.getResources().getConfiguration().navigationHidden + " nav = " + m_context.getResources().getConfiguration().navigation + " status = " + keypadStatus);
                        m_refreshRate = RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity.getRefreshRate();
                        //Log.i("yoyo", "refreshrate = "+m_refreshRate);

                        int ret = RunnerJNILib.Process(m_width, m_height, RunnerActivity.AccelX, RunnerActivity.AccelY, RunnerActivity.AccelZ, keypadStatus, RunnerActivity.Orientation, m_refreshRate );
                        if(ret ==0 )
                        {               
                            Log.i("yoyo","RunnerJNILib.Process returned 0");
                            RunnerJNILib.ExitApplication();
                        } 
                        else if(ret == 2)
                        {
                            Log.i("yoyo","RunnerJNILib.Process has returned that it is due to restart");
                            m_state = eState.Startup;
                            RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity.HasRestarted = true;
                        }
                        //Log.i("yoyo", "GameDownload.lock exists...");
                    } while( RunnerJNILib.canFlip() == false && m_state == eState.Process);                 
                }
                break;
        }
        m_renderCount--;
    }
}
```

Comment: `DemoRenderer.java:332` is the root cause. Please post the code and mention line# 332.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 sorry, but what code do you mean? My game is all written in GML.

Comment: Then who wrote this java class "DemoRenderer.java"

Comment: @Rohit5k2 The engine, I assume? I don't know anything about java. I only use the GameMaker Studio to develop my game. When I build it, it takes care of the rest.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 I managed to find the mentioned java class while searching through the internal files. It is too long to post in the comments, though; where should I post it? Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: Add that to original question as an edit.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Thanks. Added it now. I've marked line 322 with five #. Had to delete a bit of my explanation because the post was too big, but crucial information is still there.

Comment: I looked into the issue and seems like there is some issue with your bitmap. Its is not able to find its type. Try to use a different bitmap and see it it works. Your actual exception is thrown from https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/opengl/java/android/opengl/GLUtils.java line# 71

Comment: @Rohit5k2 The question is that these are all features I don't know how to access. There is no option to change bitmaps in GameMaker Studio (either 1.4 or 2). How come the game runs normally in devices with Android 7 and bellow, and crashes from Android 8 up?